# MAC OSX El Capitan: Airport Sym link not permitted

Tags: symlink, osx-elcapitan

I tried making a symbolic link to the `airport` command in MAC OS X El Capitan, using the command:

```
sudo ln -s /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport /usr/sbin/airport
```

It returned the following error:

```
ln: /usr/sbin/airport: Operation not permitted
```

Is this due to the El Capitan's "rootless" feature? The sym link worked fine in MAC OS X Yosemite.

Comment: I made an alias of the path, to resolve the issue. I am mainly asking out of curiosity.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The target directory should be `/usr/local/bin/airport`

See the article on [System Integrity Protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection) for more information as to why the directories have changed.

```
sudo ln -s /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport /usr/local/bin/airport
```

Comment: Worked for me :D